# How to create multiproject with buck?

Tags: java, android, multi-project, buck

For example I have two (A that generates apk, B that generates aar) fully configured projects (.buckconfig, .git and so on). What I need to do to make my project A depends on B? For example I want to be able to enter B project directory and type "buck build Bproject" to generate my aar. Also it would be great if there is some trick is available to make A -> (B -> C) dependency. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is coming to Buck in the future (see [issue #116](https://github.com/facebook/buck/issues/116) in the Github repository), however it is not supported yet. For now you will likely have to use a workaround, such as put both projects into the same repository or build the aar of project B, check it into the repository of project A and reference it from an [android_prebuilt_aar](https://buckbuild.com/rule/android_prebuilt_aar.html) rule.

Comment: Oh. It's pity. I am already gave it up in favor of my previous build system and hope that buck will be usable someday =)

Comment: Is this still true? Or the feature is implemented. My project A is able to use ":src" and ":res" from project B if it doesn't depend on any C (otherwise error: Attribute *** has already been defined).